# $\sum_{\text{k}\ge0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{k}\left(2\text{k}\right)!}{2^{2\text{k}}\left(\text{k}!\right)^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$?

Tags: summation

How can you compute the following summation:

$$\sum_{\text{k}\ge0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{k}\left(2\text{k}\right)!}{2^{2\text{k}}\left(\text{k}!\right)^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: I get $1/\sqrt2$.

Comment: @GEdgar Me too.

Comment: Hint: by [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k {2k\choose k} \frac{x^k}{4^k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}$$

Comment: [It's definitely](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/haaogclbdg) $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$

Comment: updated question with your result to make it beautiful, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binom formula gives that for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, $$\sum\limits_{k\geqslant 0} \binom{\alpha}{k}x^k = (1+x)^\alpha$$

By taking $\alpha  = -1/2$, we get $$\sum\limits_{k\geqslant 0} \binom{-1/2}{k} x^k = (1+x)^{-1/2}$$

Then we remark that $\binom{-1/2}{k}=(-1)^k \binom{k+1/2}{k}$.

So we have $$\sum\limits_{k\geqslant 0} \binom{k+1/2}{k}(-1)^k x^k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}$$.

And as $\binom{k+1/2}{k}=\binom{2k}{k}\cdot \frac{1}{4^k}$, we get the answer $$\sum\limits_{k\geqslant 0} \binom{2k}{k}(-1)^k \frac{x^k}{4^k} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}$$

By replacing with $x=1$, we get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

It probably was
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\binom{2k}{k}}{(2k-1)4^k} = 1$$
or the equivalent (via $k\mapsto k+1$)
$$ \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2k}{k}}{4^k(k+1)} = 2$$
which are given by the Maclaurin series of $\sqrt{1-x}$ or by creative telescoping. Since
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\cos\theta)^{2k}\,d\theta = \frac{\pi}{2\cdot 4^k}\binom{2k}{k} $$
holds by integration by parts, we also have
$$ \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sum_{k\geq 0}(-1)^k(\cos\theta)^{2k}\,d\theta=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{1+\cos^2\theta} $$
and via $\theta=\arctan t$
$$ \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{2+t^2} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$$